# SQL: the most effective way to get row number of one element

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, h2

I have a table of persons:

```
id   | Name |  Age
1    | Alex |  18
2    | Peter|  30
3    | Zack |  25
4    | Bim  |  30
5    | Ken  |  20
```

And I have the following interval of rows: `WHERE ID>1 AND ID<5`. I know that in this interval there is a person whose id=3. What is the most efficient (the fastest) way to get its row number in this interval (in my example rownumber=2)? I mean I don't need any other data. I need only one thing - to know row position of person with id=3 in interval `WHERE ID>1 AND ID<5`.

If it's possible I would like to get not vendor specific solution but a general sql solution. If it's not possible then I need solution for postgresql and h2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The row number would be the number of rows between the first row in the interval and the row you're looking for.  For interval `ID>1 AND ID<5` and target row `ID=3`, this is:

```
select  count(*)
from    YourTable
where   id between 2 and 3
```

For interval `ID>314 AND ID<1592` and target row `ID=1000`, you'd use:

```
where   id between 315 and 1000
```

To be sure that there is an element with `ID=3`, use:

```
select  count(*)
from    YourTable
where   id between 2 and
        (
        select  id
        from    YourTable 
        where   id = 3
        )
```

This will return `0` if the row doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you very much. Great solution. But if I am wrong and there is no element with id=3 in this interval how will I find it out?